# Can I ride a motorcycle in the US with a Pakistan license?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, pakistani-citizens

I'll be traveling to the US (California) soon and would like to ride a [BMW R1200GS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_R1200GS) bike that my friend owns.

I have a valid driving license from Pakistan (valid for both car and motorcycle). I understand that I can rent and drive a car in the US without the need for an IDP.

1. Does the same apply to motorcycles?
2. Do I need some special kind of
   insurance coverage? I already have travel insurance.

Comment: I think the rules vary a lot between states, where exactly are you going ?

Comment: Would your Pakistan license allow you to ride that motorcycle in Pakistan? Please edit that information into the question.

Comment: @blackbird57 Updated with sate, California.

Comment: @DJClayworth Indeed, updated the question with the information.

Comment: As noted in *[Can I legally drive a motorcycle in California with a New Zealand motorcycle license?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38950)* and in *[Which motorcycles can I ride in the US with an Israel A1 license?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58629)*, your motorcycle endorsement will be accepted (both the US and Pakistan are signatories of the 1949 [Convention on Road Traffic](http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/trans/conventn/Convention_on_Road_Traffic_of_1949.pdf)), but I would recommend obtaining an IDP nonetheless.